# Filetransfer to server, then use parameter to fill out forms?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I've successfully transferred my file over to my server, but I'm sending parameters too, how can I redirect after doing this to the page and have some forms pre-filled with these parameters? People say it's just a $_POST, but i cant get it.

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
            var title1 = document.getElementById('title').value;
            var desc1 = document.getElementById('desc').value;

            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.key = "file";
            options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

            var params = {};
            params.title = title1;
            params.desc = desc1;

            options.params = params;
            options.chunkedMode = false;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, "HTTP:HERP", win, fail, options);
            window.location.href = "HTTP:DERP";
        }
```

SERVER CODE

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["title"]))
    var_dump($_POST["title"]); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo $_REQUEST['title'];
echo $_REQUEST['desc'];
print var_dump($_REQUEST);
```